# How to Copy Large Files From AWS S3 bucket to another S3 buckets using boto3 Python API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

How to Copy Large Files From AWS S3 bucket to another S3 buckets using boto3 Python API? If we use client.copy(), it fails by throwing error as "An error occurred (InvalidArgument) when calling the UploadPartCopy operation: Range specified is not valid for source object of size:"

Answer (score 2):

As per AWS S3 boto3 API documentation, we should use multipart upload. I have googled it but could not find clear, precise answer to my question. Finally after reading boto3 api's thoroughly, I have found answer to my question. Here is the answer. This code works perfectly with multi-threading also.

Create s3_client in each thread in case if you use multi threading. I tested this method, works perfectly copying huge Terra bytes of data from one S3 bucket to different s3 bucket.

### Code to get s3_client

```
def get_session_client():
    # session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name="default")
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client("s3")
    return session, client



    def copy_with_multipart(local_s3_client, src_bucket, target_bucket, key, object_size):
        current_thread_name = get_current_thread_name()
        try:
            initiate_multipart = local_s3_client.create_multipart_upload(
                Bucket=target_bucket,
                Key=key
            )
            upload_id = initiate_multipart['UploadId']
            # 5 MB part size
            part_size = 5 * 1024 * 1024
            byte_position = 0
            part_num = 1

            parts_etags = []
            
            while (byte_position < object_size):
                #  The last part might be smaller than partSize, so check to make sure
                #  that lastByte isn't beyond the end of the object.
                last_byte = min(byte_position + part_size - 1, object_size - 1)
                copy_source_range = f"bytes={byte_position}-{last_byte}"
                # Copy this part
                try:
                    info_log(f"{current_thread_name} Creating upload_part_copy source_range: {copy_source_range}")
                    response = local_s3_client.upload_part_copy(
                        Bucket=target_bucket,
                        CopySource={'Bucket': src_bucket, 'Key': key},
                        CopySourceRange=copy_source_range,
                        Key=key,
                        PartNumber=part_num,
                        UploadId=upload_id
                    )
                except Exception as ex:
                    error_log(f"{current_thread_name} Error while CREATING UPLOAD_PART_COPY for key {key}")
                    raise ex
                parts_etags.append({"ETag": response["CopyPartResult"]["ETag"], "PartNumber": part_num})
                part_num += 1
                byte_position += part_size
            try:
                response = local_s3_client.complete_multipart_upload(
                    Bucket=target_bucket,
                    Key=key,
                    MultipartUpload={
                        'Parts': parts_etags
                    },
                    UploadId=upload_id
                )
                info_log(f"{current_thread_name} {key} COMPLETE_MULTIPART_UPLOAD COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY, response={response} !!!!")
            except Exception as ex:
                error_log(f"{current_thread_name} Error while CREATING COMPLETE_MULTIPART_UPLOAD for key {key}")
                raise ex
        except Exception as ex:
            error_log(f"{current_thread_name} Error while CREATING CREATE_MULTIPART_UPLOAD for key {key}")
            raise ex
```

Invoking multipart method:

```
  _, local_s3_client = get_session_client()
 copy_with_multipart(local_s3_client, src_bucket_name, target_bucket_name, key, src_object_size)
```